# Lagging in zoom Map

Tags: android, canvas, android-mapview

I have problem with app lagging when I have big zoom.
I have maps with markers and area, when I make zoom biger the map is lagging.
I was looking for solution, but I don't find.

Please help me with this code.

I don't have idea how I can fix it.

This is my code:

```
public class LiniaOverlay extends Overlay {

    private List<GeoPoint> m_areas;
    private Paint m_paintFill;
    private Paint m_paintStroke;
    private static final int ALPHA = 0x30ffffff;
    private static int COLORS = Color.YELLOW;
    Path areaPaths;
    static {LiniaOverlay.COLORS &= LiniaOverlay.ALPHA;}

    public LiniaOverlay(final List<GeoPoint> points) {
        m_areas = points;
        m_paintFill = new Paint();
        m_paintFill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        m_paintStroke = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        m_paintStroke.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        m_paintStroke.setAntiAlias(true);
        m_paintStroke.setStrokeWidth(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas, final MapView mapView, final boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        if (shadow) {
            return;
        }
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        areaPaths = getPath(projection, m_areas);
        drawPaths(canvas, areaPaths);
    }

    private Path getPath(final Projection projection, final List<GeoPoint> areas) {     
        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        Iterator<GeoPoint> it = areas.iterator();
        Point point = nextDrawPoint(projection, it);
        path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
                point = nextDrawPoint(projection, it);
                path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        path.close();
        return path;
    }
    private void drawPaths(final Canvas canvas, final Path path) {
       int currentColor = LiniaOverlay.COLORS;
       m_paintStroke.setColor(currentColor & 0xff7f7f7f);
       canvas.drawPath(path, m_paintStroke);
       int currentColor2 = LiniaOverlay.COLORS;
       m_paintFill.setColor(currentColor2);
       canvas.drawPath(path, m_paintFill);    
    }

    private Point nextDrawPoint(final Projection projection, final Iterator<GeoPoint> it) {
        GeoPoint geo = it.next();
        Point p = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geo, p);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Please Help me.